# Sync Schema changes automatically with Logical Replication Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I know there is limitation for logical replication to publish schema change to the subscriber. And for example if you add a column in publisher you have to **manually** add the same column to the subscriber to sync again.

Is there a workaround to do it **automatically**, tool or workflow that you use?

Comment: If a commercial product is acceptable to you, there's [EDB Postgres Distributed](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/pgd/latest/overview/bdr/ddl/)

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, logical replication does not replicate DDL. That's the first point of the documentation (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/logical-replication-restrictions.html)

What I would do is:

- store my DDL in a .SQL file
- create a small program (pick your favorite language) that will connect to all your databases (You can describe that in a simple text file) and play the same SQL file on all of them using psql

To simplify the connection, I strongly advise using a service file and a password file (for security reason if you use a password-based connection).